# mysqli_real_escape_string only works after print_r

Tags: php, mysqli

I am moving a legacy web site that was created before I started work here from an old web server (PHP 5.3) to a new one (PHP 5.5).

This site uses PEAR's DB.php.  I know it is deprecated, but to upgrade this application to MDB2 or PDO is a very large project.

I have found that in DB's mysqli.php driver, it uses an escapeSimple() function, which is essentially just a wrapper for mysqli_real_escape_string().  I found that mysqli_real_escape_string() was always returning a null or empty value.  After some searching and looking at error logs, I see that mysqli_real_escape_string will do this if the connection is empty.  But the connection is not empty.  In order to check that the connection was not empty, I have altered the function to look like this:

```
function escapeSimple($str)
{
    print_r($this->connection);
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $str);
}
```

Now I can see the connection object and everything looks in order.  The strange thing (to me anyway) is that when I put in the print_r before mysqli_real_escape_string, IT WORKS.  If I comment out the print_r, mysqli_real_escape_string returns null again.

For now, I have supressed print_r from printing to the page like:

```
function escapeSimple($str)
{
    print_r($this->connection, true);
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $str);
}
```

and the application is working, but I know this just isn't right.  I have put in a lot of time searching for this and have not come up with my exact symptoms.  Forgive me if this was solved already somewhere else.

Comment: it's probably not "empty", but a boolean false. `var_dump()` that value, then check `mysqli_error()` if it is coming back as false.

Comment: I have var_dump'd $this->connection, and it is not false.  I thought I made the clear in my post.  There are no mysqli errors to report.  Here is a snippet of the var_dump:

    ["connect_errno"]=>
    int(0)
    ["connect_error"]=>
    NULL
    ["errno"]=>
    int(0)
    ["error"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error_list"]=>
    array(0) {
    }